# Dealing Many uniform SQL table

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

I have to design a database for desktop application with WinForms and EF.
I will have many similar objects like:
1 - document1 (code,postingdate,ammount)
2 - document2 (code,postingdate,OriginDocumentCode,amount)
3 - document3 (code,postingdate,FromPerson,ToPerson,amount)
4 -
5 -

My question is:What is the best way to make tables for these objects ?
One big table with many nullable columns;
Or one small table (header) with common columns (id,code,amount) with 1:1 relation with other tables with uncommon column (tbldoc3 {headerId,postingDate,FromPerson,ToPerson});
Or separate tables for each document ignoring their common columns ?

Any help and advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is it question about designing a database or about using such model in EF?

Answer (score 2):

i think the area you should look into is called database normalization.  it'll guide you on how you should design your schemas by storing data according to the relationships within the data.

Here are some links to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/

for example, it looks like all of your objects contain 'code', 'postingdate' and 'amount' as you mentioned, so seperating that out could made sense.  ultimately you'll have to decide based on how much data is 'different'.  if its just a few columns, i'd suggest going with the simplest solution (1 table,  with nullable columns).

best of luck!